# Drools - Inserting Function-Created Object in Memory

Tags: drools

In a Drools DRL file I have a function that returns a custom object.
In a rule, I call this function and then insert the function result into memory.
However, subsequent rules do not then seem to pick up this inserted object.

If I create the object in the rule (rather than via a function) and insert it, subsequent rules are able to see it and run fine.

Code example below:

```
declare SomeObject
    value : String
end


function SomeObject createSomeObject() {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    obj.setValue("something");
    return obj;
}


rule "run first" ruleflow-group "testrules-test"
dialect "mvel"
when
    eval(true)
then
    insert(createSomeObject());     // this does not trigger the "object exists" rule
    insert(new SomeObject());       // this triggers the "object exists" rule
end


rule "object exists" ruleflow-group "testrules-test"
dialect "mvel"
when
    SomeObject()
then
    info("the object exists");
end
```

(Note that I have shown both insert methods but of course have not run with both active).

My obvious question is why does the object created by the function not get inserted into memory?

This also leads me onto the use of functions in Drools rules; should they be avoided or are there no performance or behavioural advantages or disadvantages?

Thanks.

Comment: Leaving out the ruleflow-group, this works for me using 6.1 and 6.4, so I'm inclined to suspect some other problem. Which Drools version? Does it work if you omit the ruleflow group?

Comment: It's Drools 5.4. It produces the same result with the ruleflow-group omitted.

Comment: So it's a bug. There won't be a fix for 5.4. Unless you insist on using declare, you could try a static Java method instead of the DRL function. -- Consider upgrading from this ancient version.

Comment: An upgrade project is in place, just not in time for the rules I need to write... Once upgraded I will try this again.